# Using autoprefixer with Volt

Tags: voltrb, autoprefixer

Is there a way to setup [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) in a Volt application?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but you can probably use https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails#sprockets and do the sprockets setup instructions from a .rb file in config/initializers/server/  If you get it working, let me know.

Try something like this:

```
require "autoprefixer-rails"
AutoprefixerRails.install(Volt.current_app.sprockets)
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Volt.current_app.sprockets is nil at the point the initializers are run. Do I need to require another file to initialize it beforehand?

Comment: Humm, sounds like I need to add more hooks for the boot process.  Adding it to my todo list.  If you need it now, you could probably monkey patch something in.  (Or PR's welcome)